# ETC1 compressed textures are not supported when publishing to Standalone

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, editor

I recently tried to automate my Unity build process and created an editor script which switches the platform according to where I want to build at and then starts the build process.

When I try to do the Android build everything works fine. But when I try to do the Windows Standalone build I always get this error:

**ETC1 compressed textures are not supported when publishing to Standalone**

This does not  happen when I build from the editor Build Settings menu.

This is how I did that. It works for Android but not for Windows:

```
[MenuItem("Build the Game/Windows/Build test Windows", false, 1)]
private static void BuildGameServer()
{
    EditorUserBuildSettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget(BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows);
    BuildPlayerOptions _buildPlayerOptions = new BuildPlayerOptions();

    //Get all open scenes, exclude the scene for other platform in the Array
    _buildPlayerOptions.scenes = new string[EditorBuildSettings.scenes.Length - 1];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (EditorBuildSettingsScene _scene in EditorBuildSettings.scenes)
    {
        if (!_scene.path.ToLower().Contains("client"))
        {
            _buildPlayerOptions.scenes[i] = _scene.path;
            i++;
        }
    }

    string _path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Builds", Application.productName, Application.productName + "_Server_" + Application.version + "\\" + Application.productName + ".exe");
    BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(_buildPlayerOptions.scenes, _path, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows, BuildOptions.None);
}
```

This is the log output in the console (line 92 is where it says BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer()):

> ETC1 compressed textures are not supported when publishing to
> Standalone
>
> Included from scene: Assets/Scenes/00_SPLASH.unity
> UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayer
> (string[],string,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
> BuildMenu:BuildGameServer () (at Assets/Editor/BuildMenu.cs:92)

Any suggestions? I really would appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same problem.

It works right now by removing the content from my build folder, and restarting Unity every time I make a build.
Its not very handy though, and I would love to hear if anyone has a real fix.

It seems to be related to building for different platforms. I largely have the issue if I make an Android build, and then a Windows build.